# @google-cloud/storage: A server with the specified hostname could not be found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm unable to connect even after providing my service account key file (xxx.json) in my path.

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

const getTheStuff = async () => {
        try {
          const results = await storage.getBuckets();
          const [buckets] = results;
          console.log('Buckets:');
          buckets.forEach(bucket => {
            console.log(bucket.name);
          });
        } catch (err) {
          console.error('ERROR:', err);
        }
    }
```

I try to run this but I get the following in my console. I'm not sure if the authentication has happened and something is wrong with my config, or something else entirely. Looks like the API is being treated like it's running from the google cloud env, hence the connection to an internal hostname is not possible, but this library can be used externally to, so I'm confused.

```
[Error] A server with the specified hostname could not be found.
[Error] Fetch API cannot load http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: A server with the specified hostname could not be found. (instance, line 0)
[Log] Buckets: (main.chunk.js, line 83)
[Error] Failed to load resource: The request timed out. (instance, line 0)
```

Comment: Where are you running this code? This error means that the client library has detected a Google compute service (Compute Engine, Cloud Run, etc) and access to the metadata server is disabled. If you are running on Compute Engine, what scopes are assigned to the instance?

Comment: I'm running this on my local development machine, not on google infrastructure. Also I just learnt that node.js libraries don't necessarily work in browser environments, I just moved the code to express.js and things seem to work fine now!